# Cannot assign "'str value'": "Detail table.voucher_id" must be a "Master table" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a form using my master and detail table.
Master table : TmpPlInvoic (primary key: voucher_id)
Detail table:  TmpPlInvoicedet (foreign key: voucher_id, multiple entries against one voucher id)

**Error**
**Cannot assign "'5453661'": "TmpPlInvoicedet.voucher_id" must be a "TmpPlInvoice" instance.**

I am not why i am getting this instance error. The voucher id under question is created by me and inserted in the master table. Then i try to pass the voucher id by getting it from the master table to the detail table  so that it comes as an instance.

```
tmpPlInvoicedet_save = TmpPlInvoicedet.objects.create(
            voucher_id=voucher_id,
```

**Views.py**

```
def new_invoice(request):
    logger.info('FORM INFO ----------------------------------------------')
    QuestionFormSet = formset_factory(AddRowsForm, extra=5)
    QuestionFormSet_one = formset_factory(AddRowsForm, extra=1)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    formset = QuestionFormSet(request.POST)
    temp_vid = TmpPlInvoice.objects.order_by().values_list("voucher_id", flat=True).distinct()
    items = Item.objects.all().values_list('stock_code', 'description')
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        logger.info('FORM INFO')
        new_date = data['new_date']
        new_parc = data['new_parc']
        new_vid = data['new_vid']

        item_combo = data['item_combo']
        pos_combo = data['pos_combo']
        cus_combo = data['cus_combo']
        if not temp_vid:
            voucher_id = 0
            voucher_id += 1
        else:
            voucher_id = str(int(max(temp_vid)) + 1).zfill(4)
        tmpPlInvoice_save = TmpPlInvoice.objects.create(voucher_date=new_date,
                                                         voucher_id=new_vid,
                                                         acct_id=item_combo,
                                                        particulars=new_parc,
                                                        pos_code=pos_combo,
                                                        cust_id=cus_combo
        tmpPlInvoice_save.save()
        for detail in enumerate(formset.cleaned_data, 1):
            tmpPlInvoicedet_save = TmpPlInvoicedet.objects.create(
                voucher_id=voucher_id,
                lineitem=detail[0],
                particulars=detail[1]['Rate'],
                qty=detail[1]['Quantity'],
                rate=detail[1]['Rate'],
                itemtot=int(detail[1]['Rate']) * int(detail[1]['Quantity']),
                stock_code=detail[1]['StockCode']
            )
            tmpPlInvoicedet_save.save()

    else:
        message = "wrong"
        logger.error('Form is invalid. Errors are %s', form.errors)
    return render_to_response('new_invoice.html',
                              {'formset': QuestionFormSet(), 'form': form, 'formset_single': QuestionFormSet_one},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    logger.info('Method is GET')
    form = NameForm()
    formset = QuestionFormSet()
    # logger.info('Formset from GET is %s', formset)
    return render_to_response('new_invoice.html',
                              {'formset': QuestionFormSet(), 'form': form, 'formset_single': QuestionFormSet_one},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Getting data from forms.py
**Master form**

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
combo_final = ([('', 'Select One')])
combo_final1 = ([('', 'Select One')])
combo_final2 = ([('', 'Select One')])
combo_final3 = ([('', 'Select One')])

items = list(Item.objects.all().values_list('stock_code', 'description'))
item_final = combo_final.extend(items)

pos = Positions.objects.all().values_list('pos_code', 'description')
pos_final = combo_final1.extend(pos)

cus = Custodian.objects.all().values_list('acct_id', 'description')
cus_final = combo_final2.extend(cus)

temp_vid = TmpPlInvoice.objects.order_by().values_list("voucher_id", flat=True).distinct()
if not temp_vid:
    voucher_id = 0
    voucher_id += 1
else:
    voucher_id = str(int(max(temp_vid)) + 1).zfill(4)

pos_combo = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=combo_final1, attrs={ 'class': 'select2_single form-control', 'id': 'new_loc', 'blank': 'True'}))

cus_combo = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=combo_final2, attrs={'class': 'select2_single form-control', 'id': 'new_cus', 'blank': 'True'}))

item_combo = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=combo_final, attrs={'class': 'select2_single form-control', 'id': 'new_item', 'blank': 'True'}))

new_parc = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Add Particulars', 'required':'False'}))
new_vid = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'required':'False', 'name': 'voucher_id', 'readonly': 'readonly', 'value': voucher_id}))
new_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex': '-1', 'class': 'form-control has-feedback-left', 'id': 'single_cal1','aria-describedby': 'inputSuccess2Status'}))
```

**Detail formset**

```
class AddRowsForm(forms.Form):
combo_final4 = ([('', 'Select One')])
items = list(Item.objects.all().values_list('stock_code', 'description'))
item_final = combo_final4.extend(items)

Serial = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'tabindex': '-1', 'class': 'flat', 'required':'False'}))
# table_index = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'required': 'False'}))
Particulars = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control ', 'placeholder': 'Add Particulars', 'required':'False'}))
Quantity = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Add Quantity', 'required':'False'}))
Rate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Add Rate', 'required':'False'}))
Amount = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Add Amount', 'required':'False'}))
StockCode = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Select(choices=combo_final4, attrs={'class': 'select2_single form-control', 'id': 'new_item', 'blank': 'True'}))
```

Comment: Please guys i really need help.

Comment: Because the child needs to be an instance, not just an id. Have you gone through the the tutorial? It's really a lot easier to do this than what you are trying to do.

Comment: which tutorial @MichaelJosephson? can u share the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

I later on moved to Model forms which have in-built save feature so get rid of all this hassle. If any one needs to use this method, please make sure that you create an instance of the Master table and pass it in the detail table.

```
for detail in enumerate(formset.cleaned_data, 1):
        tmpPlInvoicedet_save = TmpPlInvoicedet.objects.create(
            voucher_id=voucher_id,
            lineitem=detail[0],
            particulars=detail[1]['Rate'],
            qty=detail[1]['Quantity'],
            rate=detail[1]['Rate'],
            itemtot=int(detail[1]['Rate']) * int(detail[1]['Quantity']),
            stock_code=detail[1]['StockCode']
        )
        tmpPlInvoicedet_save.save()
```

to

```
for detail in enumerate(formset.cleaned_data, 1):
        tmpPlInvoicedet_save = TmpPlInvoicedet.objects.create(
            voucher_id=TmpPlInvoice.objects.filter(voucher_id=voucher_id),
            lineitem=detail[0],
            particulars=detail[1]['Rate'],
            qty=detail[1]['Quantity'],
            rate=detail[1]['Rate'],
            itemtot=int(detail[1]['Rate']) * int(detail[1]['Quantity']),
            stock_code=detail[1]['StockCode']
        )
        tmpPlInvoicedet_save.save()
```